# VML v:shape , V:roundrect elements ain`t displayed correctly in IE6, IE7 in strict mode

Tags: internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, vml

Does anybody can provide an answer to such issue? I`m trying to put some vector graphics into HTML. Actually it is not necessary in mine case, so I probably would resort to simple image for now, but I as encountered a problem, I couldn't resolve, it's became very interesting and relevant to the future to define what is going wrong.  VML is absolutely new to me, by the way.

I tried to insert several vml-elements into a page, and some of them worked perfectly (in IE6, IE7) namely "oval", "rect". But when I've attempted to insert a shape or roundrect everything went wrong.

Actual question is: **is there satisfactory VML support in IE6, IE7 or what I'm doing wrong?** But as far as I'd examined my code everything is right in it. Below I'll put a sample, so everyone could test this in IE-browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1  /DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>sample</title>

<style>

  v\:* { behavior: url(#default#VML); display:inline-block}

  #div1 {

    width:400px;

    height:400px;

    background-color:#e4fe56;

  }

</style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="div1">

    <v:shape style='width:100px;height:100px' fillcolor="red" path="m 0,0 l 30,0,30,30 xe" />

    <v:rect style='width:100pt;height:75pt' fillcolor="blue" strokecolor="red" strokeweight="3.5pt"/>

    <v:roundrect style='width:100pt;height:75pt" arcsize="0.3" fillcolor="yellow"   strokecolor="red" strokeweight="2pt"/>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Additionally I found that it happens only in strict mode. When  DOCTYPE removed or with other conditions when IE works in quirks mode everything works well.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use SVG instead of VML. I know IE7/8 doesn't support SVG, but there are libraries which can convert it pretty easily, and it will mean you'll be ready for the upgrade to IE9 (or another browser) when the time comes.

Comment: Thank you. In my case I've already resorted to gif image, cause I need to support IE6 and 7, where SVG does not work. But it is interesting what's happening. As I understood , IE does not display correctly VML shapes and roundrects in strict mode at all. At Microsoft site ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932175 ) it is pointed that in strict mode it is necessary to add vml\:* {display:inline-block} , but for me it did no change.

Comment: Did you try a non-strict doctype, such as the XHTML-Transitional or HTML5 doctype, rather than XHTML Strict? That might make a difference.

Comment: By the way: Re using SVG instead: As I said, there are a number of libraries that convert from one to the other. eg http://code.google.com/p/svg2vml/ among others. Also the [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) library is excellent for producing cross-browser vector graphics in a Javascript API. VML is not supported anywhere except IE6, IE7 and IE8, so it's of limited use.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion about libraries. I'll try them in future, but in my current project it is better to use image, for there is no need for dynamic change of the image, and image size is only 1kb, when Raphael's size is more than 40 kb.

Comment: About 'strict' doctype. Sorry for confusion. I actually meant not 'strict' doctype of the document, but STANDARD browser mode. I mixed up these terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mismatched quotes on your style attribute

```
<v:roundrect style='width:100pt;height:75pt"
```

You have whitespace in your doctype:

```
/xhtml1  /
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've despaired to find a solution and decided that it does not work. There is also one strange thing here. <v:shape>-element was not displayed until I added explicitly dimension-units, namely px or pt in style-attribute, whereas on Microsoft site such code example is present <v:shape
   fillcolor="green"
   style="position:relative;top:1;left:1;width:200;height:200"
   path = "m 1,1 l 1,200, 200,200, 200,1 x e">
   </v:shape>   There is no units specified in style and it is not displayed. Don't you know whether I'm doing wrong or it's a mistake on microsoft site?

Comment: The unit requirement is an [undocumented change for standards compliance](http://louisremi.com/2009/03/30/changes-in-vml-for-ie8-or-what-feature-can-the-ie-dev-team-break-for-you-today/).